How to get access for writing to resource file with setup project?
I have a game project where I add a line into .txt doucument. Then I've created a Setup project for this game. And after installing and running the shortcut on the desktop. And if try to add a line I get an error:

Access to the path "C:\Program Files\WB\WordsGameSetup\Resources\citiesVocabulary.txt" is denied.

I've tried two variations of add method but both don't work.
public void AddWordToVocabulary(string word)
{
    File.AppendAllText(Path, word + Environment.NewLine);
    Vocabulary.Add(word);
}

public void AddWordToVocabulary(string word)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
        stream.WriteLine(word);
    Vocabulary.Add(word);
}

